# No space left on device even with only 44% usage and 3% inode usage

Tags: filesystem, disk-usage

Recently I downloaded a large dataset (~100GB) containing lots of images and small txt files in a .zip file. When I try to unzip it using `unzip dataset.zip`, the first 30% unzipped fine but then it shows

```
checkdir error:  cannot create dataset/data_name.jpg
             No space left on device
             unable to process dataset/data_name.jpg.
```

I checked both `df -h` and `df -ih` and both shows I have plenty of storage on my device:

```
tengyu@tengyu-MS-7A12:/media/tengyu/2THDD/dataset$ df -ih
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             7.9M   585  7.9M    1% /dev
tmpfs            7.9M   731  7.9M    1% /run
/dev/sda3        3.4M  530K  2.9M   16% /
none             7.9M     2  7.9M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             7.9M     3  7.9M    1% /run/lock
none             7.9M   124  7.9M    1% /run/shm
none             7.9M    32  7.9M    1% /run/user
/dev/nvme0n1p2      0     0     0     - /boot/efi
/dev/sda1       1001M   22M  979M    3% /media/tengyu/2THDD
/dev/nvme0n1p4    65M  6.3M   58M   10% /media/tengyu/BC9C613B9C60F0F6
/dev/nvme1n1p2    30M  2.1K   30M    1% /media/tengyu/DB

tengyu@tengyu-MS-7A12:/media/tengyu/2THDD/dataset$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G  4.0K   32G   1% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  1.7M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/sda3        53G   39G   12G  78% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             32G  254M   32G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/nvme0n1p2   95M   30M   66M  32% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1       1.8T  766G  979G  44% /media/tengyu/2THDD
/dev/nvme0n1p4  477G  419G   58G  88% /media/tengyu/BC9C613B9C60F0F6
/dev/nvme1n1p2  470G  352G   94G  79% /media/tengyu/DB
```

The drive I'm using is `/dev/sda1` or `/media/tengyu/2THDD`.

I know that this is a frequently asked question on AskUbuntu but I've went through a lot of the Q&As and couldn't find anything useful in my case.

Comment: I wonder if it's some bug of unzip. Maybe try `7z x`?

Comment: How big do you expect the uncompressed file to be?  You might simply not have enough room -- zip can easily do 20x expansion on text files.

Comment: @TomYan I tried using `7z x`. It also gives the same error.

Comment: @ubfan1 When I ran `df` the disk already has the first 30% of the zip expanded and it still only uses 44% of 1.9TB. The uncompressed file shouldn't be 2X larger than the compressed one as it is mainly jpg images and txt files with only numbers in it.

Comment: Did you test the zipfile with unzip -tq   and unzip -Z  ?  The unzip man page does not say any temporary files are used, but your root, and thererfor /tmp only has 12G.

Comment: @ubfan1 I didn't test with tq and Z flags but I tried unzipping into another disk which had only 200GB free disk space and it worked. I think somehow the disk space of my 2THDD is not as large as it says.